# .NET Backgroundworker - Is there no way to let exceptions pass back normally to main thread?

Tags: .net, winforms, backgroundworker

QUESTION: Re use of .NET Backgroundworker, is there not a way to let exceptions pass back normally to main thread?

BACKGROUND:

- Currently in my WinForms application I have generic exception handle that goes along the lines of, if (a) a custom app exception then present to user, but don't exit program, and (b) if other exception then present and then exit application
- The above is nice as I can just throw the appropriate exception anywhere in the application and the presentation/handling is handled generically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BackgroundWorker` automatically passes back the exception.  It's in the [AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error.aspx) property when you hook the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

If you like, you can wrap and rethrow the exception in this event handler - keeping in mind that there's a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/433765/control-invoke-throws-exception-getbaseexception-rather-than-the-actual-exception) in the framework that will cause the "outer" exception to be thrown instead because you're in the middle of an `Invoke`.

An exception that occurs on a background thread in a .NET application is a catastrophic error that can and will bring down the entire process; the only way to deal with this is to wrap all of the activity in a try-catch block and save any exception that occurred, which is exactly what the `BackgroundWorker` does.

Comment: @Aaronaught - did you mean "that will cause the "inner" exception to be thrown"?  (thanks for responding)

Comment: Got it!  I just created a new BusinessException inside backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted and set the innerException to "null".

Answer (score 2):

If the asynchronous method called by DoWork throws an exception, that exception will be made available to the RunWorkerCompleted handler.  You can handle it there.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
    ...
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error.aspx):

> If an exception is raised during an
>   asynchronous operation, the class will
>   assign the exception to the Error
>   property. The client application's
>   event-handler delegate should check
>   the Error property before accessing
>   any properties in a class derived from
>   AsyncCompletedEventArgs; otherwise,
>   the property will raise a
>   TargetInvocationException with its
>   InnerException property holding a
>   reference to Error.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

Instead, you can make a class that inherits `BackgroundWorker` and overrides `OnRunWorkerCompleted` to check `e.Error` and run exception handler if it's not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the static [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) event?